# Php email is never sent, i dont know why

Tags: php

the link is http://creeper9207.com/register.php?code=2&&mto=EMAIL ADRESS HERE

```
<?php
$to = $_GET['to'];
$subject = 'SixtyCraft Confirmation Mail';
$message = 'Confirm code: '. $_GET["code"];
mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried executing this code. I am sure that it will produce parse error.

Comment: Look at this line: $to =". $_GET["to"] ."; and try to fix it.

Comment: You need a mail server, local or remote.

Comment: There can be several possible reasons for the mail not to be sent. Post some more relevant code which you have tried. Check you sendMail() function. Change `$to =". $_GET["to"] .";` to `$to=$_GET["to"];`

Comment: change `$to =". $_GET["to"] .";` to  `$to =$_GET["to"];`

Comment: I suggest you to add these lines while testing:

   ``ini_set('display_errors',1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
   error_reporting(-1);``

To see all errors and warnings.

Comment: Note that the original code had a syntax error that has been "corrected" by another user. This is problematic for two reasons. 1: The error may have been the cause of the OP's problem, and the edit may have rendered the question unanswerable. 2: The edit has rendered the existing answers ill-fitting.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this..**

```
//Change $to =". $_GET["to"] ."; to $to = $_GET["to"];

<?php
$to = $_GET["to"];
$subject = 'SixtyCraft Confirmation Mail';
$message = 'Confirm code: '. $_GET["code"];
$headers = "From: your@example.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `" .` and `. "` on the first line.

Consider checking your PHP error log.

Your web page is probably unsafe. You should send the mail when the user creates their account or at least use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: I tried you're suggestion, it still didnt work, and also this isnt a create-an-account website, a program that doesnt have email capabilities is telling it what to do

Comment: i got it to send once, but i cant make it work a second time for some reason